# How to disable Jenkins /login page after enabling SAML plugin?

Tags: azure, jenkins, saml

I am using this SAML plugin for SSO in Jenkins https://plugins.jenkins.io/saml/.
Before that it used Jenkins own user database and an admin user for everybody. The plugin works - it gets Azure login page and user gets redirected to Jenkins main view. Although if I go on my Jenkins url and add /login, then it gives me the login page, but the security realm is only SSO, so that would mean there is no way in signing in with the admin user - this happens even when user is authenticated.

Is there a way to disable or possibly redirect from /login to the main url?

Comment: If you have an LB you could add a redirect rule there.

Comment: @ycr I think you mean redirect uri after authentication with Azure. This is actually working with redirecting to /securityRealm/finishLogin, but the problem is that if I have bookmarked /login page, then even if I am authenticated it goes to the login page. This is just confusing to the developers, because we have enabled SSO on some environments.

Comment: No I mean if someone tries to go to /login redirect to Azure Login page. If they are already logged in they will be redirected to the main page.

Comment: Okay, I am new to Azure and Jenkins, but according to this under Azure redirect uri description I would assume this is where the tokens are sent: "The URIs we will accept as destinations when returning authentication responses (tokens) after successfully authenticating or signing out users. The redirect URI you send in the request to the login server should match one listed here." But if you go to Jenkins /login page it does not initially make authentication request to Azure.

Comment: By that description I would assume that I need to create redirect inside Jenkins from /login page to Jenkins base url, where it tries to do the authentication request to Azure.

Comment: checkout this: https://www.datawiza.com/blog/technical/protecting-jenkins-using-the-datawiza-access-broker-single-sign-on-and-granular-access-control/

You can define groups in Azure AD and it can map groups in Azure AD to different roles in Jenkins, e.g. admin role. 

It is free if you have no more than 25 users.

Comment: Hello! I think you misunderstand. The SSO is working with security groups, I have my own role based groups in Azure. The problem is the still existing Jenkins own default login page, cause even if you have chosen another security realm that does not use the /login path, the page still exists. So before my changes, we used 1 user only, now we have Azure SSO and security groups already working. All of Jenkins users are not always aware what is going on and then they end up on Jenkins login page (which does not and should not work), probably from earlier bookmarks and so on.

Comment: Then they assume that SSO is not working or something like that. So what I actually need is:                                                                                                                         1st option) Redirect from https://{jenkins_url}/login to https://{jenkins_url}              2nd option) Disable /login page (then it should actually redirect to base path if path is missing